# DataProtection.EntityFramework raise an expcetion with Postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I had the same problems with the Postgresql database. To manage migrations, I'm using EF. I received this strange issue when attempting to add a migration to the application. I never had this problem before I started using SQL server.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
     ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P01: relation "DataProtectionKey" does not exist
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass160_0.<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
       at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkCoreXmlRepository`1.GetAllElements()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.GetAllKeys()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow, Boolean forceRefresh)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRing()
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
      Exception data:
        Severity: ERROR
        SqlState: 42P01
        MessageText: relation "DataProtectionKey" does not exist
        Position: 22
        File: parse_relation.c
        Line: 1381
        Routine: parserOpenTable
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
       at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Protect(IDataProtector protector, String plaintext)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter`2.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`2.<SanitizeConverter>b__0(Object v)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetValue(ColumnModification columnModification)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.ToList()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDataOperations(DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IModel source, IModel target)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

I am using:

1. .net core 3.1
2. EF 3.1.13
3. Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFramework 3.1.13
4. Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.11

my application db context have this definition

```
....
 public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }
 public DbSet<DataAudit> AuditTrail { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Settings> Settings { get; set; }
 public DbSet<ApiResourceEntity> ApiResources { get; set; }
....
```

DbContext definition

```
serviceCollection.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("MyAPP")
                .PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG();
```

**EDITED:**
I commented this code and the migration has passed so the issue is this code on the OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) method:

```
 foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
                {
                    var attributes = property.PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedAttribute), false);
                    if (attributes.Any())
                    {
                        property.SetValueConverter(new EncryptedConverter(_dataProtectionProvider));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any Idea could be helpful.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

First you need to run the Skoruba project.Identity Server 4.Admin. He will roll migrations. And only then launch Skoruba.Identity Server 4.STS.Identity! You're probably doing the opposite...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question I am posting if anyone is still looking for a solution.

All it needs to do is add configuration for the "DataProtectionKeys" entity and it is fixed.

```cs
public class DataProtectionKeyConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DataProtectionKey>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DataProtectionKey> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("data_protection_keys");
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("id");
        builder.Property(x => x.Xml).HasColumnName("xml").HasMaxLength(1000);
        builder.Property(x => x.FriendlyName).HasColumnName("friendly_name");
    }
}
```